# Consultas sobre SQL ¿Seria correcto este modelo para una tienda online? [IMAGEN]

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, mysql-workbench

Estoy aprendiendo base de datos por mi cuenta con SQL Workbench tanto a codigo como a traves de diagramas. En este caso use un diagrama porque me parecio mas practico y rapido.

Mi primer pregunta seria sobre la forma correcta de relacionar:
Hay datos que se repiten en las tablas porque cada una representa lo que quiero que muestre en diferentes secciones de mi tienda. Asi que cree index en cada campo que queria relacionar de las tablas y la mayoria de las claves foraneas las cree **desde** la tabla Factura. Por eso en la imagen que adjunto hago hover en factura. Alguna sugerencia para saber si esto esta bien?

La otra pregunta tiene que ver con el tipo de relacion, entiendo que hay de uno a muchos, muchos a muchos etc. Cuando las genere no vi una forma de indicarlo y me parece que tal vez estoy confundiendo conceptos. De hecho, no sabria como hacerlo.
Lo que mas me importa es entender si de esta manera los datos ingresados que son redundantes entre tablas se relacionan de tal forma que no se dupliquen innecesariamente.

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos y muchas gracias!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos. De BD, normalización y esas cosas no intervengo en desarrollos (salvo excepciones); debes empezar a construir primero lo que serán tus catálogos; si éstos tendrán alguna relación crear primero el que será FK de otro; teniendo tus catálogos entonces sigues con tus tablas (digamos) de detalles, por ejemplo primero se compra y paga; entonces te pueden hacer la factura **compra(id_compra[otros campos y su definición])** para tener **factura(id_factura int, id_compra (FK)[otros campos y su definición])**.

Comment: Vas a generar una factura por producto ? En la tabla factura tienes factura id y product I’d

Comment: No termino de entender el motivo por el que has hecho este diseño, pero pregunto: ¿una factura puede tener varios productos, no es así? Entonces, lo ideal sería que tuvieras la tabla facturas, la tabla productos y la tabla que relaciona facturas con productos, con una relación de N:N (de muchos a muchos). Esa tercera tabla tendrá un mínimo de 3 campos: un PK que puede ser id_profact, y dos FK: factura_id y producto_id.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy viendo que tienes algunos datos duplicados que no son realmente necesarios en mas de una tabla. Por ejemplo los valores de nombre y apellidos puedes obtenerlos desde la tabla de cliente y no serian necesarios en facturas, a no ser que puedas tener que un cliente necesite la factura a nombre de otra persona lo cual requiere que este en esa tabla pero no se debería poner la relacion. Pasaría lo mismo con los campos de dirección.

El punto en estos diseños es repetir el menor numero de veces los campos para no tener varias veces la misma información. Ten en cuenta que si se cumplen los casos que te he expuesto seria buena idea tener una tabla de direcciones_clientes y otra de receptores.

Comment: Podrías haber hablado de la [Normalización de bases de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos). Eso habría sido valioso.